# Sql wildcard not end string

Tags: sql, sql-like

I try to write sql query with a condition where the word doesn't contain letters 'ON', 'EN' at the end.

I tried:

```
WHERE word = '%[^ON]' and word = '%[^EN]'
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, you would use `not like`:

```
WHERE word NOT LIKE '%ON' AND word NOT LIKE '%EN'
```

Some databases support regular expressions, so this can be simplified, say, to:

```
WHERE word NOT REGEXP '(ON|EN)$'  -- MySQL syntax
```

But `LIKE` suffices.

Comment: That needs to be `REGEXP 'ON$|EN$'` (or you need to add some parens). Or just `'[OE]N$'`.